# How do I get multiple max values in python dictionary?

Tags: python

so I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
foo_dict = {'A' : 0.03, 'B' : 0.13, 'C' : 0.42, 'D' : 0.42}
```

And I got the maximum  value with this line :

```
max_value = max(foo_dict.values())
```

As you see, the maximum value is 0.42 and there are two keys with that value-C and D.
Now I want to get both C and D in a list. I've tried

```
max_key = max(foo_dict.keys(), key=lambda k : foo_dict[k])
```

But it only gives C. How do I get both(all) keys that have the same value that is `max_value`?

 Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506694/python-dict-more-than-one-max-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
max_value = max(foo_dict.values())
[k for k,v in foo_dict.items() if v == max_value] # ['C', 'D']
```

`max` function can only return one value at a time. So you can find the max value using the first line, store the value and later loop over the dict and pick up the keys where value match with the max value.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.